# What is the best way to show two questions in a single screen.

Tags: forms, user-expectation, web-app, questionnaire

I'm working on a questionnaire, part of a web app. Until now the admin could form a questionnaire with different question types and rearrange them accordingly. Now it is needed to add the following functionalities: Show 2 questions in the same screen simultaneously. Don't make both of them mandatory. And finally make, in selected cases, the 2nd question to appear conditionally (depending on the 1st answer).

I was wondering how to show the multiple questions to the end user and if by making it clear and show all this different types of questions would result to a better UX.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As I understand in your questionnaire every question is on a single screen. What is the reason to have two questions on the same screen? I ask to better understand the need. I think on a user perspective it is confusing to have usually one question per screen an every now end then there are two questions. This would rise the chance that the user misses the secend question...

Comment: The 2 question screens appear in the case where the questions are relevant. e.g. the user answers that prefers a given brand and the 2nd question tries to clarify why. I hope I made it clear. 

I agree with you that going from 1 question to 2 and then 1 again is confusing. I'm searching for a way to minimise the "damage" that this is causing .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would avoid putting two questions on one screen. Since this can be confusing to the user. You could insert the second question to a new screen, this means you would have to relate to the previous question. Somthing like: "You answered with XY would you like to share more information" or putting the Answer into the new question like "Please tell us why you prefere "XY".

[image]